# Javascript function being called again while it is still running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, locking

I have a javascript function that is called when the user clicks on a button and performs an AJAX query that adds some data to my database.  However, I've been getting complaints that a lot of data hasn't been getting through, and I've isolated the problem to be the time between clicks.  When they wait long enough between clicks, the data always gets through, but if they don't wait long enough it's a crapshoot.

So I'm pretty much settled that the problem is that the javascript function is being called again while it is already running, which I shouldn't allow.  Is there a way I can lock the user's browser at the beginning of the function and unlock it at the end after the AJAX?  I know this may irritate my users, but I can't see any other solution.

It's not totally necessary, but here's what my javascript function looks like:

```
function addtolist(thisform, sdata)
{
    var scntDiv = $('#p_data');
    var request = $.ajax({ async: false, url: "php_addtolist.php", type: "POST", data: {data:sdata}, dataType: "html" });
    request.done(function(msg) { outdata = parseInt(msg); });
    $(outdata).appendTo(scntDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it seems like the `outdata` is async. the following should resolve.

```
function addtolist(thisform, sdata)
{
    var scntDiv = $('#p_data');
    var request = $.ajax({ async: false, url: "php_addtolist.php", type: "POST", data: {data:sdata}, dataType: "html" });
    request.done(function(msg) { 
        outdata = parseInt(msg); 
        $(outdata).appendTo(scntDiv);
     });

}
```

Comment: Also should make `outdata` be a local variable, not an implicit global.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button when the function is called, then re-enable it with the `complete` callback:

```
function addtolist(thisform, sdata)
{
    $('#submit_btn').prop('disabled', true);
    var scntDiv = $('#p_data');
    var request = $.ajax({ 
        async: false, 
        url: "php_addtolist.php", 
        type: "POST", 
        data: {data:sdata}, dataType: "html" },
        complete: function() { $('#submit_btn').prop('disabled', false); }
    );
    request.done(function(msg) { outdata = parseInt(msg); });
    $(outdata).appendTo(scntDiv);
}
```